# split full name to first ,middle and last in x++ d365fo

Tags: string, axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

i want to split full name to first ,middle and last in x++ d365fo

```cs
str fullName = _contracts.fullName();

// Replace any non-ASCII whitespace characters with regular spaces
fullName = strReplace(fullName, '\u00A0', ' '); // Replace non-breaking spaces with regular spaces
fullName = strReplace(fullName, '\t', ' ');    // Replace tabs with regular spaces

// Trim any leading or trailing whitespace characters from the full name
fullName = strTrim(fullName);


// Split full name into first, middle, and last name
str firstName;
str middleName;
str lastName;

// Find the last space character to split the full name into first and last name
int lastSpace = strFind(fullName, " ", strLen(fullName), -1);
if (lastSpace >= 0)
{
    lastName = subStr(fullName, lastSpace + 1, strLen(fullName));

    // Find the first space character to split the full name into first and middle name
    int firstSpace = strFind(fullName, " ", 0, 1);
    if (firstSpace >= 0 && firstSpace < lastSpace)
    {
        firstName = subStr(fullName, 1, firstSpace - 1);
        middleName = subStr(fullName, firstSpace + 1, lastSpace - firstSpace - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        // No space found before last space, assume the full name is just a first name and last name
        firstName = "";
        middleName = "";
    }
}
else
{
    // No space found, assume the full name is just a first name
    firstName = fullName;
}
```

this is how the object passes
"fullName":"mh ali hasan"

i got lastname ="mh ali hasan"
sounds like he doesn't recognize the spaces

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Review the [documentation of the strFind function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-ref/xpp-string-run-time-functions#remarks-5), particularly the "Remarks" section, which contains an explanation how the negative `_number` parameter works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to. Modify as needed to handle special characters or other circumstances.

> `[firstName, middleName, lastName] = DirPerson::splitNameParts("John Michael Smith");`